# Is it possible to install appx(windows phone 8.1 app) to windows phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

Is it possible to install appx(windows phone 8.1 app) to windows phone 8? If it is possible then how?

Answer (score 1):

No it's impossible. Cause appx is WinRT app and it's not supported by wp8. You need to update your phone.